# Run Lambda Layer Function in Lambda

Tags: java, node.js, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I created one Lambda. In that lambda, I need to add one existing Layer. The Lambda is in java and lambda layer is in NodeJS. How can I call a function from the layer in the lambda?

I am able to call if both the runtime environment is NodeJS.

```
import createRequire  from '/opt/index.js';

export const handler = async(event) => {
    let t = await createRequire.f1(event);
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: t,
    };
    return await createRequire.f2(response);
};
```

I want to call the f1() and f2() in my Java Lambda.

Comment: AWS Lambda is irrelevant here. You can't directly call a JavaScript function from Java.  You'd need to exec node.js to parse and run the JS code but that's a bad idea generally. If you aren't able to write both pieces of code in the same programming language then consider making one of them an API or separately-invoked Lambda function.